# Nodes created on 1st date of the month are not showing up on Calendar

Tags: datetime

I am using the following modules

1. [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar)
2. [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date)

There is an attendance content type with a field of type date.
The nodes of this content type get pulled in a Calendar.

But, nodes which are created on the 1st date of the month are not showing up in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you are A> using a "date contextual filter" and "page by date" or B> you are simply showing content in a calendar.

If it's B>, check your date filter and make sure you have "greater than or equal to" set to ensure the first day gets included.